# Python 3.9 logger RotatingLogger doesn't write anything into file

Tags: python, logging

##### I created a simple demo to test my Django project.

when i invoke unittest, everything passed and i set logger.info to record log into `debug.log`.
There should be some records appeared in my target file but nothing in it.
[image: debug.log]

here is my Logger.py

```
import logging.config
import os

fmt = "%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(filename)s:%(lineno)d|%(message)s"
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# dir
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
log_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'logs')

if not os.path.exists(log_path):
    os.mkdir(log_path)

log_file = os.path.join(log_path, "debug.log")

file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    # 'debug.log',
    log_file,
    backupCount=10,
    encoding='utf-8'
)

logging.basicConfig(
    format=fmt,
    datefmt=datefmt,
    handlers=[file_handler],
    level=logging.INFO
)

# logging.DEBUG
# logging.INFO
# logging.WARNING
# logging.ERROR
# logging.CRITICAL

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

also here is the main endpoint

```
import json
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, file_data
import api.KeywordApi as kwa
from commons.\
    Logger import logger


@ddt
class loginInterfaceTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @file_data('../testDatas/testdata_interface_login.yaml')
    def test_login(self, **params):
        print("{:*^50s}".format("the first correct answer"))
        path = "/dologin/"
        data = {
            "username": params['username'],
            "pwd": params['password'],
            "randomCode": "1234"
        }

        # 2：send request
        res = kwa.do_post(path, data)

        # 3：assert
        self.assertEqual(200, res.status_code, "fail:{}".format(res.status_code))
        print('text', res.text)
        # print(type(res.text))
        logger.info(type(res.text))
        # logger.info(res.text)
        print(json.dumps(res.json(), indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
        self.assertEqual(params['code'], res.json()['code'], 'failed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Any ideas? A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if type(datas[key]) == 'str' and datas[key].startswith('<') and datas[key].endswith('>'):
```

In the decoration use eval function to deal with datetime format

After i changed if to this it works:

```
if type(datas[key]) == str and datas[key].startswith('<') and datas[key].endswith('>'):
```